# Count mirror reflections of yourself

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

You are placed in a room without windows. The room is air-tight. The shape of the room is a cylinder and you are placed in its center. The whole surface of the room is covered with mirrors.

How many images of yourself you could see in this room?

Comment: How come I am in a room without mirrors but the rooms surface is covered with mirrors? Seems quite contradictory

Comment: the room is without windows. Fixed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> None!

Because

> Since you are completely enclosed inside the room, there is no light, so you can't see anything!

Comment: Moreover, you'd soon run out of oxygen and suffocate, so even if there was enough light to see, you wouldn't be able to do so for very long.

Comment: You are assuming that there is no light source inside the room. What if the person was carrying a light source?

Comment: @AdityaDev Then the OP would've said 'you are carrying a candle' or something.

Comment: even if you were carrying a light, i don't think you'd see an image of yourself anyway---everything would be way too distorted

Comment: My problem is how you get there in first place? They build it around you or teleport you inside Star Trek style?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Two hollow half-cylinders covered with mirrors. You go in front of one, the other one is moved behind you. Tape them together.

Answer (score 5):

> I would see 3 images of myself; one on the floor, one on the ceiling and one stretched and distorted around the cylindrical side wall. This is of course after pulling out my phone and turning the light on like a rational human adult.
>  Edit: The double mirror effect would occur as seen in this image. 
>  [image: A view of two people in an elevator with parallel mirrors, creating the infinitely repeating mirror effect. One man is holding a camera, but he does not repeat at all due to his first reflection blocking all subsequent reflections. The woman to his left however appears to repeat because she is offset from the camera.] 
>  Notice that when an object is offset from the viewer's perspective a seemingly infinite repeating image appears. But notice that after several reflections this repetition only represents fractional reflections of the viewer. In short: the number of total reflections is equal to the number of reflective surfaces summed with the repeating fractional reflections of the double mirror effect.

Comment: What about the reflection of the floor in the ceiling and vice-versa?  Since they're parallel you'd see infinitely many reflections.

Comment: Upon further reflection: If you have a phone, then you should turn on the camera and take a selfie of yourself with your infinite reflections, and the reflections of the images of the reflections on the screen, and the ...

Comment: @2012rcampion I might see the edge of a reflection behind me, but I will not be able to see the entire 2nd reflection due to the 1st reflection being in the way and so on. 

I will concede that the total reflections visible then increases to some irrational amount greater than 3, but not reaching 4 due to information lost after the first reflection.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder Good point.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are talking about my physical image, I would go with NONE as there are no windows and its air tight.

Comment: I think you mean there arent windows

Comment: Yes, I meant Windows!! :)